# Weird GLM perspective problems with my 2D Game

Tags: opengl, 2d, graphics-programming, glm, pc

I am trying to create the graphics system of a 2D game using OpenGL 3.3.
To help me in this task I am using the GLM math libraries.

However I am having some trouble. When my objects (for now they are just squares) have  a different scale, they "slide" through each other. I am posting some examples below.

In this picture both objects are at the center and camera is centered at the center[image]

In this other picture the code has only moved the camera, but for some reason the big square moved down faster than the smaller one
[image]

Here are the matrices I am using to transform my camera

```
  // Projection matrix : 120° Field of View, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 10000000 units
  glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(3.141516f/1.5f, (float)_WindowWidth / (float)_WindowHeight, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
  
  //glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 16.0f, 12.0f, 0.0f,  0.1f, 100000000.0f);
  // Camera matrix
  glm::mat4 View       = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(CameraPos.x, CameraPos.y ,2.0f), // Camera Position
    glm::vec3(CameraPos.x, CameraPos.y ,1.0f), // Where the camera looks
    glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // This is another way to say camera is not rotated
  );
```

And here are my matrices for my model transform

```
  glm::mat4 ViewProj = View * Projection;

  // Object to world matrix
  glm::mat4 Model      = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(ElementToDraw.Position.x, ElementToDraw.Position.y, 1.0f)) * 
      glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), ElementToDraw.Rotation, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) *
      glm::scale(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(ElementToDraw.Scale.x, ElementToDraw.Scale.y, 1.0f));

   
  glm::mat4 MVP = Model * ViewProj;
```

I really don't know why this happens. Am I using some matrix wrong?

Another thing, this only happens on the axis of the different scale. If both objects have the same scale they don't "slide"

Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I tried using glm::ortho with the following parameters:

```
 glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f,  0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am passing the MVP using shaders

But the sliding continued and the objects werent centered at the center of the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to change this line:

```
glm::mat4 MVP = Model * ViewProj;
```

To this line

```
 glm::mat4 MVP =  ViewProj * Model;
```

I made some research and it seems that in DirectX its the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your World matrix multiplication order.

What you do is

**W** = **T** * **R** * **S**;
where **W** is the world transform, **T** is translation, **R** is rotation, and **S** is scaling.

You should instead use:

**W** = **S** * **R** * **T**.

THis is because matrix multiplication **is not commutative**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried using ortho but it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct parameters for that? This function takes very different parameters than that of perspective...

Comment: Yes and the sliding continued happening

Comment: It was even more exaggerated

Comment: Ah! got it!... getting it in an answer...

Comment: You mean in my Model matrix?

Comment: It still happens

Comment: It didn't change anything the sliding continues at the same rate(although oddly the objects initial positions moved)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17448/discussion-between-blastxu-and-the-light-spark).